# Quick Fix - Adding Attribute to extension org.eclipse.ui.ide.markerResolution

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

I am implementing QuickFix in my RCP application.

I added org.eclipse.ui.ide.markerResolution and created a class implementing IMarkerResolutionGenerator2 interface.

```
public class MyResolutionGenerator implements
    IMarkerResolutionGenerator2 {

    @Override
    public IMarkerResolution[] getResolutions(IMarker marker) {
        ....
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasResolutions(IMarker marker) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I also created resolutions and everything is working fine.

Moment I add attributes to extension points org.eclipse.ui.ide.markerResolution, the quick fix option in the problem view always comes disabled.

```
<extension
  point="org.eclipse.ui.ide.markerResolution">
    <markerResolutionGenerator
        class="com.priyank.visual.quickfix.MyResolutionGenerator"
        markerType="com.priyank.test.model_marker">
        <attribute
            name="test"
            value="testdata">
        </attribute>
</markerResolutionGenerator>
```

No exceptions thrown nothing but I am not able to figure out the reason for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution. Mistake was at my end only.

The attribute added must be present in the marker. Attribute added test was not present for the marker com.priyank.test.model_marker, hence the hasResolution from MarkerHelpRegistry was returning false :)